# System.Net.Mail некорректно валидирует email

Tags: c#, email

Делал валидацию имейлa, решил использовать System.Net.Mail, всё таки от Майкрософта, а не использовать регулярные выражения. Так вот валидация успешная даже если имейл не верный.

**Вопрос:** это у всех так или я что-то делаю не так?

Код валидации:

```
public static Email? Create(string email)
{
    .......
    if (!MailAddress.TryCreate(email, out var mailAddress))
        return null;

    return new Email(email);
}
```

Тест:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("something here")] // success
[InlineData("something@here")] // fail
[InlineData("s@s.s")] // fail
[InlineData("s@ssssss.s")] // fail
[InlineData("something@.co")] // success
public void Create_When_EmailIsInvalid_Should_ReturnFailureResult(string email)
{
    // act
    var email = Email.Create(email);

    // assert
    email.Should().BeNull();
}
```

P.S. использую .NET Core 6.0.305

Comment: Microsoft [рекомендует](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) использовать пакет [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). Так что лучше меняйте способ валидации.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!